# How to adjust ARIMA model for structural breaks?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, arima, sas

I am trying to make an ARIMA forecast using the PROC ARIMA step, however there seems to be structural breaks in the data and when this is present it invalidates ARIMA results. I figure I can dummy out the dates that contain a structural break, however I am not sure how to integrate this into the ARIMA forecast. How do I include those dummy's (or whatever the proper way with dealing with structural breaks is) into the ARIMA procedure?

Comment: It isn't clear if you are asking how to use PROC ARIMA, or if you are asking what the logically appropriate way to set up this analysis is. Note that if you are asking about how to use SAS, that would be off topic here. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I am asking how to conduct the BOX Jenkins methadology with structural breaks present in the data because the structural breaks dilute the results...